# `uname -r` shows same kernel after aptitude upgrade has completed successfully

Tags: upgrade, kernel, virtualbox

Running

```
uname -r
```

in a terminal gives an output saying *3.13.0-37-generic*, but I am trying to upgrade the kernel to 3.16, and indeed I have ran

```
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

which installed *linux-headers-3.16.0-34* (3.16.0-34.45), but running `uname -r` doesn't show that. I am doing all this because it seems to me that virtualbox dkms can't find a kernel source for 3.13.

Comment: "... upgrade the kernel to 13.6 ..." ?

Comment: Ok, how to do that via terminal? I thought that just installing the linux header for 3.16 will upgrade the kernel!

Comment: You have a typo: "... upgrade the kernel to 13.6 ..." There is no kernel 13.6.

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Comment: I meant 3.16. I think I just don't know how to upgrade the kernel, I thought that just installing a specific kernel header will upgrade the kernel to that version.

Comment: I haven't rebooted the system, but does this mean that just installing a kernel header version will upgrade the kernel to that version? There was already an older 3.16.x version installed, but uname -r was also outputting 3.13!

Answer (score 1):

`uname -r` reports the *running kernel*. Switching to the newly installed kernel doesn't happen on-the-fly.

The newest kernel will be booted by default, so after rebooting the system normally, `uname -r` returns `v3.16.0-34-generic`.

Comment: I have indeed rebooted the machine but the kernel still hasn't changed! What can I do?